# Detect click on textbox in form

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I want a certain function to be run every time someone clicks on a textbox in my form. So far I have managed to detect when it gets focus and when it is doubleclicked, using the following two eventhandlers, but I am unsure about **how to catch when it is clicked once while it already has focus**.

Does anyone here have any experience with catching such an event? I don't seem to find any obvious suspects in the dropdown-menus of the VBA editor.

```
Private Sub tbxTil_DblClick(ByVal Cancel As MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Me.tbxTil = format(oppdater_dato(CDate(Me.tbxTil)), "dd.mm.yy", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
End Sub

Private Sub tbxTil_Enter()
    Me.tbxTil = format(oppdater_dato(CDate(Me.tbxTil)), "dd.mm.yy", vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Mouse events, something like this:

```
Private Sub tbxTil_MouseDown(ByVal Button As Integer, ByVal Shift As Integer, ByVal X As Single, ByVal Y As Single)
   MsgBox "Click"
End Sub
```

Comment: This works to a certain extent, however if I use a mouseclick to enter the textbox, both this and the `tbx_enter` event fires. I suppose it may be some way to handle that though... Thanks for the help!